# An(other) integral inequality

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Let $q\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ and $f \colon X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable functions.

> **My question:** Is it true that
>   \begin{align}
> \int_{X} \int_{X}q(x)^{2} f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} x\, \mathrm{d} y\geq \int_{X} \int_{X} q(x)q(y) f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} x\,\mathrm{d} y ?\quad (\star)
> \end{align}

**Some comments.** I sketch my attempt to prove it in the spoiler box below.

> We can rewrite the LHS of the to-be-proven inequality as \begin{align} \int_{X} \int_{X}q(x)^{2} f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} x\,\mathrm{d} y&\overset{(\#)}{=} \int_{X} \int_{X}q(y)^{2} f(y,x)\, \mathrm{d} y\,\mathrm{d} x \notag\\ & = \int_{X} \int_{X}\left(\frac{q(x)^{2}+q(y)^{2}}{2}\right) f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d} x\,\mathrm{d} y, \end{align} and since $q(x)^{2}+q(y)^{2}\geq 2q(x)q(y)$ for all $x,y\in X$, we are done.

> For $(\#)$ to hold $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ must be symmetric. Is this a necessary condition for $(\star)$ to be true?

Comment: In # you are just renaming variables. The next equality doesn't really follow from # alone, though.

Comment: Doesn't the last equality require $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for it to be true?

Comment: Yes, in my attempt symmetry of $f$ is required. Is this also a necessary condition for the inequality in my question to hold true?

Comment: You definitely need to assume that $f$ is non-negative, also.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure wheter wolfram just put out crap, but try $q(x)=e^x and f(x,y)=(1/x)*e^y$ as a counterexample. (X=(0,2))

Comment: @axioman: on $X = (0,2)$ both integrals diverge, due to the $1/x$ factor in $f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, obviously you need $f(x,y) \geq 0$. Otherwise there are easy counter examples.

Next, let me give a counterexample when $f(x,y)$ is not symmetric in $x,y$.

Let $X = (0,2)$ and $f(x,y)$ be defined to be $0$ when $y\in (0,1)$ and $1$ when $y\in [1,2)$.

Let $q(x)$ be defined to be $\frac12$ when $x\in (0,1)$ and $1$ when $x\in [1,2)$.

$$ \iint_{X\times X} q(x)^2 f(x,y) ~\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \frac14 + 1 = \frac54 $$

while

$$ \iint_{X\times X} q(x) q(y) f(x,y) ~\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \frac12 + 1 = \frac32 $$

(Notice that

$$ \iint_{X\times X} q(y)^2 f(x,y) ~\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = 2 $$

and $2 + \frac54 \geq 3 = 2 \times \frac32$.)

Comment: As an aside: typically integral inequalities of these forms do not depend on the precise form of the measure used, which means that often times it suffices to first think about the case of sums. For sums examples are much easier to compute.